# Proper way to call a lambda function?

Tags: vue.js, axios, httprequest, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I am building an app with vue.js, severless and aws lambda function.
I dont know what is the proper way to call a lambda function, and so far my initial solution is:

1. set up an api in api gateway for that function which generates a link.
2. hard code that link inside my vue frontend and use axios as my http client to make request.

But my problem is:

1. Is hard coding the url inside the frontend a proper thing to do?
2. if I have multiple lambda functions then I will have a bunch of urls, and that does not seem like a good way to implement this.

in my main.js of the vue frontend I had this set up:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    mandatorySignIn: true,
    region: config.cognito.REGION,
    userPoolId: config.cognito.USER_POOL_ID,
    identityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: config.cognito.APP_CLIENT_ID
  },
  Storage: {
    region: config.s3.REGION,
    bucket: config.s3.BUCKET,
    identityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID
  },
  API: {
    endpoints: [
      {
        name: "Test",
        endpoint: config.apiGateway.URL,
        region: config.apiGateway.REGION
      },
    ]
  }
});
```

if my approach is correct, do I add multiple endpoints under the API config since i have more then one lambda function? and if not whats the proper way to implement this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick glance at the [docs here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/getting-started/q/platform/js#manual-setup-import-existing-rest-api) shows that the recommended setup is to set `endpoint` to the base URL of the Api Gateway.  For example, if you navigate to the Api Gateway, under "Dashboard", you should see a link similar to the following:

`https://1234567.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Stage`

This is the link that you should be setting `endpoint` to.

Then, you would use it like so:

```
API
  .get("Test", "/path/to/lambda")
  .then(response => {
    // Add your code here
  })
```

Reference [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/restapi/fetch/q/platform/js#get-requests) for usage

However, if you're using regional endpoints, as referenced [here](https://qzas9lfub4.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Stage/), then your setup is correct, and you would then need to create a new entry for each lambda you have.  This is recommended against by the Amplify team though.

Rather than hardcoding, I would recommend setting these URLs as environment variables, which give you a lot more flexibility on deployments.

Comment: Thanks! In this way no Axios is needed for my api to works.

Comment: That is correct, however the Amplify states in their docs that they are using Axios under the hood for these requests.